# Find $f(x)$ given $f, g$ such that $\,f(0) =2,\, g(0) =1, \, f'(x) = g(x),\, g'(x) = f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions satisfying:

$$\begin{align} f(0) & =2\\
g(0) &=1 \\
f'(x) &= g(x) \\
g'(x) & = f(x)
\end{align}$$

Find $f(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: Please add or show your significant work. SO that we can help you

Comment: Hint: differentiate one of your equations and substitute another one in it.

Answer (score 3):

By your hypothesis,

$g'(x)=(f'(x))'=f''(x)$

But also, $g'(x)=f(x)$

That is, $f''(x)=f(x)$, as in $f''(x)-f(x)=0$

Solving the differential equation at hand, we have:

$f(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$

$f(0)=2$, that is, $c_1+c_2=2$

Also, $g(0)=1$, that is $f'(0)=1$, resulting in $c_1-c_2=1$

Solving those two equations, we get:

$c_1=\frac{3}{2}$

$c_2=\frac{1}{2}$

Finally,

$f(x)=\frac{3}{2}e^x+\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$

Done.